# How to configure Spring Cloud Zipkin Server with MySQL for persistence?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-cloud, zipkin

Which exact dependencies and `application.yml` configuration are required for Spring Boot/Cloud Zipkin server (potentially Zipkin Stream server) to persist the tracing data using MySQL?

Comment: You ask a question and answer within a minute???

Comment: stackoverflow has also an option to provide an answer with the question like q/a style. i posted it here because i thought it would be helpful for people like me trying to get this working. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: Oh ok. I expected the format of that option to be different. Interesting. Learning something new everyday haha.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The official documentation was helpful, but I think it didn't include all the dependencies explicitly (at least as of now). I had to do some extra research for samples to get all the required dependencies and configuration together. I wanted to share it, because I believe it could be helpful for someone else.

**Spring Boot version:** `1.4.0.RELEASE`

**Spring Cloud version:** `Brixton.SR4`

**POM:**

```
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.zipkin.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>zipkin-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.zipkin.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>zipkin-autoconfigure-storage-mysql</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.zipkin.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>zipkin-autoconfigure-ui</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
   ...
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Brixton.SR4</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

**Java:**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import zipkin.server.EnableZipkinServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZipkinServer
public class ZipkinServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ZipkinServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**application.yml:**

```
spring:
  datasource:
    schema: classpath:/mysql.sql
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/zipkin?autoReconnect=true
    username: root
    password: admin
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    initialize: true
    continue-on-error: true
  sleuth:
    enabled: false
zipkin:
  storage:
    type: mysql
```

**References:**

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/

Comment: You can post your remarks here in this issue - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/255 . We're trying to gather all the knowledge from different storages

Comment: Here is the repo with working code https://github.com/nitinware/Trace-Sleuth-ZipKin